# Python : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IP'

Tags: python, excel

My code below getting error , I am writing this code to read the header present in excel sheet and writing data into excel sheet based on their rexpective column.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
book = open_workbook(r'Book1.xls')                                                                                
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)     
wb= copy(book)    
w_sheet  = wb.get_sheet(0)    
keys = [sheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in range(sheet.ncols)]
print(keys)
WriteList= [{'IP': '100.43.23.22', 'Credential': 'admin2' , 'phone-num' : '99884'},
            {'IP': '100.43.23.42', 'Credential': 'admin3' , 'phone-num' : '99884'},
            {'IP': '100.43.23.52', 'Credential': 'admin4' , 'phone-num' : '33334'}]
nrow=sheet.nrows
for i in keys:
    for dict1 in WriteList:
        print(i,dict1.get(i))
        #w_sheet.write(nrow,i,dict1.get(i))
nrow+=1
print("modified")
wb.save('Book1.xls')
```

error in line

```
w_sheet.write(nrow,int(i),dict1.get(i))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IP'
```

Comment: You can't convert the string `'IP'` to `int`, that's the problem

Comment: Well, yes, "IP" is a string and can't be converted to an integer. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Check now, but still getting same error

Comment: @ettanany Check now, still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions (for code clarity's sake)

1. `for key in keys` looks better then `for i in keys`
2. `for dictionary in WriteList` looks better then `for dict1 in WriteList`

As for the error. You're trying to convert a key (i) from the excel sheet to an integer (which is a string I assume). Removing `int(i)` should do the trick.